# Minimum Cost Path using Recursion

Tags: python, recursion

I tried finding the minimum cost path using recursion not dynamic programming, unfortunately the result is not right, I tried debugging the code myself, too many recursions, I could not follow.

```
A = [[6,2,4,1],
    [1,2,5,4],
    [2,7,3,2],
    [1,2,2,5],
    [9,5,1,6]]
```

With the above matrix and start point A[0][1] the MCP = 2,1,2,2,1 = 7

Allowed directions are only down and diagonal (up to bottom)

My Code result 3:

```
def minSumRekursive_helper(A, n ,c):

    max_n = len(A)
    max_c = len(A[0])

    if (n >= max_n or c < 0 or c >= max_c):
        return 0

    minSum = min(
        minSumRekursive_helper(A, n+1, c-1),
        minSumRekursive_helper(A, n+1, c+1),
        minSumRekursive_helper(A, n+1, c)
    )

    total = A[n][c] + minSum
    return total
```

If someone could help me, where the above code goes wrong?, I appreciated.

Comment: You might want to include the desired start and end of the path in the question. I am guessing you want a path from any cell of the upper row to any cell of the lower row, but that is only a guess.

Comment: Also, your code is using `x` for ordinate and `y` for abscissa, which is the opposite of what everyone else in the world is doing.

Comment: Correct, I'd like to start from any number in the first row as long as result to minimum cost path and I'll swap x and y.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks every one, I found the error regarding c, I separated the if into two ifs then changed c to c = 0 if it gets out of bound. This changed mad sure to return 0 only if the n gets out of bound.

Here is the full code

```
def minSumMultiStart(A):
    minSum = float('inf')
    max_n = len(A)-1 # bottom-up
    max_c = len(A[0])

    for i in range(max_c):
        minSum = min(minSum, minSumRekursive(A, max_n, i, max_c))

    return minSum


def minSumRekursive(A, n, c, max_c):

    if not (c >= 0 and c < max_c):
        c = 0

    # Bleiben innerhalb A
    if n < 0:
        return 0

    total = A[n][c] + min(
        minSumRekursive(A, n-1, c-1, max_c),
        minSumRekursive(A, n-1, c+1, max_c),
        minSumRekursive(A, n-1, c, max_c)
    )

    return total


A = [[6,2,4,1],
    [1,2,5,4],
    [2,7,3,2],
    [1,2,2,5],
    [9,5,1,6]]

print('Result:',minSumMultiStart(A))
```

The previous

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your code comes from these two lines:

```py
if (x >= max_x or y < 0 or y >= max_y):
        return 0
```

You are mixing two different conditions in this `if` statement:

- if `x >= max_x`, that means we have arrived at destination;
- if `y < 0 or y >= max_y`, that means we have crashed into a wall.

These are two very different situations, and the return value should be different. So I suggest cutting these two situations into two `if` statements, and think carefully about what to `return` in each of those two different situations.

**Remark:** Your code is using `x` for ordinate and `y` for abscissa, which is the opposite of what everyone else in the world is doing. The computed executing the code doesn't care one way or another, but humans reading the code in the future will care. I suggest swapping the two letters.

Comment: I'll swap x and y then try seperate the if, thanks.